# NUnit test fails unexpectedly in Async testing of a C# app

Tags: c#, nunit, task-parallel-library, task, moq

Having the following interface and class, I am trying to nunit test them but the test fails and I can't find out the reason.

```
public interface IService
{
 Task<double> GetAccDetails(int personId);
}

public class Person
{
 private int _personId;
 private IService _service;

 public Person(int personId, IService service)
 {
    _personId= personId;
    _service = service;
 }

 public double Amount {get; set;}

 public async Task UpdateBanckingAcc()
 {
    Amount = await _service.GetAccDetails(_personId);
 }
}
```

And this is the unit test:

```
[Test]
public async void Test1([Values(200)]int personId)
{
 const double expectedResult = 20;    
 var serviceMock = new Mock<IAccountService>();

 var taskCompletion = new TaskCompletionSource<double>();
 taskCompletion.SetResult(10);
 serviceMock.Setup(x => x.GetAccDetails(It.Is<int>(id => id == personId)))
        .Returns(taskCompletion.Task);

 var person = new Person(personId, serviceMock.Object);

 await person.UpdateBanckingAcc();

 double res = person.Amount;
 Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, res);
}
```

What's wrong with this test?

Answer (score 3):

Assert message says for itself:

> Expected: 20.0d
>
> But was:  10.0d

Your expected result is 20 however you mistakenly stub GetAccDetails() with value of 10. Change following line and your test will pass:

```
taskCompletion.SetResult(20);
```

Comment: `taskCompletion.SetResult(expectedResult);` is probably better.

Comment: sorry, but this is not the issue, I just put random numbers when published this post. So the numbers are correct

Comment: I run your test with corrected number and it passed. What error do you get when test fails?

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by CodeFuller, you are providing a different value to the task than your expected value.

You should also use the `ReturnsAsync` method when setting up the mock and also make the test async (You want to avoid using `async void` when creating asynchronous methods unless it is an event handler which is an exception to the rule).

```
[Test]
public async Task Test1([Values(200)]int personId) {
    //Arrange
    double expectedResult = 20.0;

    var serviceMock = new Mock<IAccountService>();

    serviceMock
        .Setup(x => x.GetAccDetails(It.Is<int>(id => id == personId)))
        .ReturnsAsync(expectedResult); // User ReturnsAsync here

    var person = new Person(personId, serviceMock.Object);

    //Act
    await person.UpdateBanckingAcc();

    var actualResult = person.Amount;

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, actualResult);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I found the issue: I forgot to add the keywork Task into the signature of the method